# What is this sentence structure called?

Tags: syntax, terminology

I'm writing a paper about Donald Trump's speaking style and he frequently says sentences like the following:

"They wanna be in the United States of America. **That’s where they wanna be**."

"We’re gonna send you reinforcements and we’re gonna send them to you quickly. **That’s what we’ll do**."

What would be the correct linguistic term to describe the sentences in bold? I figure they are some kind of cleft construction, but I'm not sure and would be very happy if somebody could help.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an ordinary unmarked sentence to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"X is wh-relative clause" is an inverted pseudo-cleft: https://glossary.sil.org/term/pseudo-cleft-sentence.

The X is itself a sentential anaphor, and the relative clause predicate restates the previous statement predicate; so the whole sentence is a restatement of the preceding statement, and does not introduce any new information (something uncharacteristic of cleft constructions). You could call it a pseudo-cleft tautology, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at these sentences from a [figures of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech) point of view, one may call this structure a [syntactic pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Syntactic_pleonasm).