# "It is ___ that/who + verb." pleonasm vs. "___ + verb."

Tags: terminology, figure-of-speech

Is there a name for the following type of pleonasm:

- "It is John who runs." (instead of: "John runs.")
- "It was congress that legislated." (instead of: "Congress legislated.")

?

Comment: Are you just looking for *cleft sentence*? Personally I would call your example a pleonasm because it has a distinct function from the alternative.

Comment: Related question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28737/what-is-this-sentence-structure-called/28762#28762

Comment: Yes, it's called an **_it-_ cleft** construction.

Comment: That's what we said in ELU. Apparently they want a second opinion. There are [a lot of different kinds of syntactic cleavage](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammars such as *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002) refer to such sentences as *it*-clefts.

Note that *John runs* does not have the same meaning as *It is John who runs*, and that the two examples may not even have the same truth values in the same contexts. The second is not a pleonasm.

We can show this through the following type of example:

> A: “We know one of the girls runs” 
> B: “It’s John who runs”

Compare B's response above with their one below:

> A: “We know one of the girls runs” 
> B: “John runs”.

In the second scenario A’s sentence might still be correct. In the first B is saying that A is mistaken. (Assuming that John in both cases is male)

Comment: How don't they have the same meaning?

Comment: @Geremia  A: “We know one of the girls runs” B: “It’s John who runs” versus A: “We know one of the girls runs” B: “John runs”. In the second scenario A’s sentence might still be correct. In the first B is saying that A is mistaken. (Assuming that John in both cases is male)

Answer (score 0):

No, I won't call it a passive voice. I'd describe it as a figure of speech, namely some kind of [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) using more words than strictly necessary to transport the information.

Comment: Yes, it's a sort of pleonasm, but is there a word for this specific sort of pleonasm?

Comment: I am not aware of such a specialised term, but this does not preclude its existence.

Comment: They're called "Cleft constructions" (_it_-cleft as here, but also _wh_-clefts like _What he did was leave fast_, as well as others, like [_Nobbut_-clefts](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf).)